# Corollary 4.4.1. in A. Lasota, "Chaos, Fractals, and Noise", 2nd Ed.

Tags: measure-theory

I hope to ask to clarify a paragraph in the book, "Chaos, Fractals, and Noise", 2nd Ed, by A. Lasota. The paragraph, in page 72, right above Corollary 4.4.1, states that: "we note that, since P is linear, convergence of ${P^nf}$ to $1$ for $f \in D$ is equivalent to the convergence of ${P^nf}$ to $<f,1>$ for every $f \in L^1$. This observation is, of course, valid for all types of convergence: Cesaro, weak, and strong."

I want to know the detailed derivation of the proof for the part: the two convergences are equivalent. I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: It would help if we had a better idea of what you don't understand. You don't understand "linear"? You don't understand $f\in D$? You don't understand $\langle\,f,1\,\rangle$? You don't understand "Cesaro, weak, and strong"?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for your reply. I understand what linearity for PF operator means, knows definition of density set D, different Lp sets, and also different kinds of convergence definitions. What I want is the proof of how these two convergence are equivalent.